# \r character in shell script

Tags: shell

I get the below error while trying to execute a shell script,

```
$'\r': command not found: line 2:
```

Please suggest a solution for the same.

Below are the intial lines used in the script,

```
#!/bin/sh

if [[ $# -lt 1 ]]; then
   echo "ERROR Environment argument missing <dev,test,qa,prod>"
   export RC=50
   exit $RC
fi
```

Comment: Please post the entire script or enough of it to allow people to reproduce the problem

Comment: \r\n is a windows end of line.. did u write it in windows? if so, just retype it up :P

Comment: #!/bin/sh

if [[ $# -lt 1 ]]; then
   echo "ERROR Environment argument missing"
   export RC=50
   exit $RC
fi

Comment: whoa, don't retype it: `dos2unix` it

Comment: @Mohan, ...btw, `[[ ]]` is only guaranteed to be valid with `#!/bin/ksh`, `#!/bin/bash`, or another extended interpreter; with `#!/bin/sh`, only `[ ]` or `test` are guaranteed to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)

Comment: Don't `export` a variable just before you exit the script, that's completely pointless.

Answer (score 40):

Your problem is that the file has Windows line endings. This can be caused by editing a file in Windows and trying to run it on a non-Windows system.

You can fix this problem using `dos2unix` to convert the line endings:

```
dos2unix ConstruedTermsXMLGenerator.sh
```

The corresponding utility to convert in the other direction is `unix2dos`.

Some systems have `fromdos` and `todos`.

Comment: @Mohan, if you ftp your script from windows to *nix, make sure you transfer it as ascii. If you scp it, you have to use `dos2unix` on the remote side. Or use a text editor that can save in "unix" format.

Comment: Notepad++ on Windows using Ansi codification does this to sh files. Use "Save as unix bash file" instead "Save".

Comment: This is the perfect answer and should have been picked as the final answer.

Answer (score 22):

You can use **`sed -i 's/\r$//' scriptname.sh`**

Replace the scriptname with actual script name.

Answer (score 17):

I used notepad++ to convert the line endings.

**Edit** > **EOL Conversion** > **UNIX/OSX Format**

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error and what I did was to transform the characters `'\r'` to `'\n'`. using this line:

```
tr '\r' '\n' < oldfile.sh > newfile.sh
mv newfile.sh oldfile.sh
chmod +x oldfile.sh
./oldfile.sh
```

I think you could also delete the '\r' characters by using:

```
tr -d '\r' < oldfile.sh > newfile.sh
```

`tr` is the command trasnform, and the `-d` is delete the following character.

I think the shell actually doesn't like `'\r'` character.

Answer (score 1):

I got a different error message when running your script under `/bin/sh`, but when I switched to `/bin/bash`, it worked fine:

```
$ cat foo.sh
#!/bin/sh
if [[ $# -lt 1 ]];
    then echo "ERROR Environment argument missing"
    RC=50
    exit $RC
fi
$ sh foo.sh
foo.sh: 6: [[: not found
$ bash foo.sh
ERROR Environment argument missing
```

You've built in a [bashism](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism). This may or may not be a big deal for your organization. If you want to keep using `bash`-specific features, change the shebang line to `#!/bin/bash` and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks sarnold for the response. I tried the same script after changing to bash and with debug turned ON. I still get the error, Below is the output,                                               $ bash -xv foo.sh
#!/bin/bash

+ $'\r'
: command not foundnerator.sh: line 2:
if [[ $# -lt 1 ]]; then
   echo "ERROR Environment argument missing <dev,test,qa,prod>"
   export RC=50
   exit $RC
fi
ConstruedTermsXMLGenerator.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
ConstruedTermsXMLGenerator.sh: line 7: `fi'

Comment: @Mohan, then perhaps @Sigtran is correct; did this file originate on Windows? If so, run `dos2unix` or `dtox` or one of those similar sorts of tools to remove all the extra `\r` characters from the file.

Comment: But, the same script works fine when it is placed in /tmp directory and executed. How is this possible?

Comment: Running it with `bash -vx` is wrong if the shebang says `#!/bin/sh`, or vice versa.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact issue when creating a .sh file on a Mac (unix) and executing it in Linux.
Turns out that I had to set FileZilla FTP settings to '*Binary*' transfer type:

- "*Settings>Transfers>File Types>Default transfer type*" to "*Binary*" (instead of "*Auto*")

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace `'\r'` with `''` (nothing), this will do the trick.
If you have any GUI editor (Notepad++) recommended directly find/replace.

If you are only doing it on Linux server then use something like:

`sed -i 's/old-text/new-text/g' input.txt`

But Since `'\r'` comes only if you have edited it in windows as it's a new line character (`\r\n`), so first method should work.