# Shell script works in the console but not when saved as a text file

Tags: shell, cygwin, newline

Consider this simple shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
fruitlist="Apple Pear Tomato Peach Grape"
for fruit in $fruitlist
do
   if [ "$fruit" = "Tomato" ] || [ "$fruit" = "Peach" ]
   then
      echo "I like ${fruit}es"
   else 
      echo "I like ${fruit}s"
   fi
done
```

When I paste it to a cygwin window it works fine however when I save it as a text file test.sh and run it from the cygwin terminal I'm getting this:

```
$ ./test.sh
./test.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
'/test.sh: line 4: `do
```

However, if I remove newlines it works:

```
#!/bin/sh
fruitlist="Apple Pear Tomato Peach Grape"
for fruit in $fruitlist
do if [ "$fruit" = "Tomato" ] || [ "$fruit" = "Peach" ]
   then echo "I like ${fruit}es"
   else echo "I like ${fruit}s"
fi done
```

How can I make the script more readable by maintaining new lines in the file, `\n` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You have added some weird characters in the DOS -> UNIX conversion. Try to use `dos2unix` to the file to "clean" it.

Comment: Might have indeed, I have ademded the question with more useful information, see if you can help now?

Comment: What shell (+version) are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [\r character in shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230798/r-character-in-shell-script)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `\r` characters come from a Windows file, where the new lines are defined with `\r\n`. In UNIX the new line is defined just with `\n`, hence the `\r` stays "orphan" and causes these problems.

What you can do is to convert the file to UNIX mode with the command [`dos2unix`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html).

More info in: [Does Windows carriage return \r\n consist of two characters or one character?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7013341/1983854):

> Two characters combined represent a new line on Windows. Whereas on
>   Linux, `\n` represents new line. It moves cursor to the start of new
>   line on Linux. On Windows, the cursor will stay at the same column in
>   the console but on the next line.
>
> - `\r` is carriage return;
> - `\n` is line feed.

Answer (score 1):

Not answering the question.

A `case` statement would fit well here. As well as an actual array.

```
fruitlist=( Apple Pear Tomato Peach Grape )
for fruit in "${fruitlist[@]}"; do
    case $fruit in
        Tomato|Peach) echo "I like ${fruit}es" ;;
        *) echo "I like ${fruit}s" ;;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I always add the following header to my shell scripts to let cygwin ignore CR:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$OSTYPE" = "cygwin" ]; then shopt -s igncr 2>/dev/null; fi # New version of Cygwin complains itself of CR
```

Note that the comment at the end of the second line is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

To fix cygwin's running of scripts that have windows end-of-line characters, without editing scripts or installing dos2unix:

**Add these lines to `~/.bash_profile`, and then re-start cygwin**:

```
export SHELLOPTS
set -o igncr
```

[Credit](https://ptolemy.berkeley.edu/projects/chess/softdevel/faq/5.html).