# How to run the bash scripts file?

Tags: bash, shell

The following bash scripts can be executed one by one in my debian7 console.

```
apt-get update
apt-get -y upgrade
apt-get install -y build-essential  gcc  libtool  libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev  openssl  libssl-dev
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.0/Python-3.4.0.tgz
tar xf Python-3.4.0.tgz -C /usr/local/src/
cd /usr/local/src/Python-3.4.0/
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/python3.4  --with-ensurepip=install   
make 
make  install
ln -s /usr/local/python3.4/bin/python3.4   /usr/bin/python3.4
```

Why can't be executed by the command `bash -x /root/initial.sh` when i save all the command in the file `/root/initial.sh`?

root@online:~# . /root/initial.sh

```
E: Invalid operation update  
E: Invalid operation upgrade  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done  
E: Unable to locate package libssl-dev  
-bash: $'\r': command not found  
--2014-10-24 12:02:20--  https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.0/Python-3.4.0.tgz%0D  
Resolving www.python.org (www.python.org)... 103.245.222.223  
Connecting to www.python.org (www.python.org)|103.245.222.223|:443... connected.  
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found  
2014-10-24 12:02:20 ERROR 404: Not Found.  

tar: /usr/local/src/\r: Cannot open: No such file or directory  
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now  
: No such file or directoryython-3.4.0/  
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory  
ln: failed to create symbolic link `/usr/bin/python3\r': File exists  
-bash: $'\r': command not found  
-bash: $'\r': command not found  
-bash: $'\r': command not found  
-bash: $'\r': command not found  
-bash: $'\r': command not found
```

It is strange that i nano the /root/ini.sh in putty console,there is just one line in it:

```
apt-get update
```

When i input :

```
sh /root/ini.sh 
E: Invalid operation update
```

There is no relationship betwwen my ini.sh and  '\r' ,what is the matter?

think to kamaln7 in digitalocean forum.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-run-the-bash-scripts-file

```
sudo apt-get install dos2unix
dos2unix /root/initial.sh
sh  /root/initial.sh
```

it is ok.
But problem remains.

```
1.In gvim for windows
```

i have set  configuration in ~vimrc .

```
set fileformat=unix
```

When i save the file in gvim and sent it into my serverip, sh  /root/initial.sh  can not make it run.
E: Invalid operation update and -bash: $'\r': command not found

```
2. In notepad++

Edit -> EOL Conversion--unix format.
```

same problem remain.

Is the transmission process cause the problem ?
i change the window format with gvim or notepad++,but the transmission process change it 
from unix format into window format again?

My client system is  win7, i have to work in win7 environment , it is inconvenient for me to  change the file format with  `dos2unix   mytarget.sh`  and then `sh mytarget.sh` .
How can i solve the problem in gvim for windows and notepad++ ?

Comment: Please post the error message.

Comment: Explain "can't be executed"

Comment: The `'\r'` characters look a bit suspicious. Have you written/copied the script from a windows machine by any chance?

Comment: yes ,it is written in the notepad in window7.

Comment: Windows line endings are different from Unix/Linux line endings. bash doesn't know how to handle Windows line-endings. Create the file with an editor on Linux.

Comment: possible duplicate of [\r character in shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230798/r-character-in-shell-script)

Comment: i have copy it into gvim in win7 ,upload it into vps,problem remain,how can i do?

Comment: use dos2unix on the file and see if \r goes away! OR use notepad++ editor and before saving the file, use "Edit > EOL Conversion > Unix/OSX format" and then save it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Remove the `-x` parameter. If that doesn't work, try

```
. /root/initial.sh
```

Mind the space.